# When best to perform iCloud Sync

Tags: objective-c, ios, icloud

I'm syncing a list of table view items via iCloud. When would be best to perform the sync. Here is my understanding of the various options.

**didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** - this will only get called when the app is launched. As most users send the app to background, rather than quit, it is likely this method won't be called very often.

**applicationWillEnterForeground** - this will happend every time the app is opened from a background state, if the internet connection is slow, this could cause a pause is the UI displaying?

**applicationDidEnterBackground** - I believe we only have 5 seconds to perform any actions, so a slow connection might mean we can't sync.

What are your thoughts best time to sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, besides the fact that a document saves every so odd amount of seconds, the best time to sync with iCloud is very dependent on the circumstance.

For example, if you have created a brand-new object that would be lost if not stored to iCloud, it's probably a good idea to do a sync with iCloud right away.

On the contrary, if you have created a brand-new object that wouldn't be lost if not stored to iCloud due to it being saved within Core Data, then maybe you can combine the save into one elsewhere given that you're concerned about the speed and CPU that the sync will take up.

Comment: It's basically a todo list application. I fire off a sync when the users creates a new item. So saving to iCloud I think I've got the correct method. It just I'm not sure when to retrieve. I'm thinking maybe everytime the table view reloads, I'm just not sure if that will effect performance...

Comment: If you're afraid of a sync affecting the performance of your app in that sense: don't be afraid to setup a loader that waits until the sync is completed.

Comment: I really didn't want to go the loader route, that's why I wondered if I could put it in a smarter location such as when the app goes to background

Comment: In your case, I would really advise using a loader. You don't want your user to create the new item, and then check it off before iCloud is done syncing because iCloud will not be able to receive that newly checked item without crashing. I can't imagine why you would want to avoid a loader. They're a very necessary part of using iCloud.

Comment: how about running the sync in a background thread? Would that help with performance?

Comment: Sure, but that's what I'm saying. What if the user has a slow connection, and your sync runs in the background for a long time. Why risk the user crashing by doing another action while the iCloud sync is going on in the background?